# Unable to add more entries to Firebase after 11

Tags: database, firebase, unity-game-engine, account

I have a database in firebase that is meant to hold user data and I'm able to get it to add account data up to number 10 (zero based), but after that, anytime I call the function to add to the database it doesn't show up in Firebase. I am using this for a game in Unity. Here are the function calls.

`

```
public void populateDatabase()
{
    //populate static account data
    AccountData _thisAccount = new AccountData();

    _thisAccount.accName = Account.instance.NickName();
    _thisAccount.accEmail = PlayerAccount._this.getUserEmail();
    _thisAccount.accCash = 100;
    _thisAccount.accGem = 100;

    //Ranking Values
    _thisAccount.Rank = 0;
    //rookie
    _thisAccount.RookieRank = 0;
    _thisAccount.RookieAverage = 0;
    _thisAccount.RookieScoreOne = 0;
    _thisAccount.RookieScoreTwo = 0;
    _thisAccount.RookieScoreThree = 0;
    //Amature
    _thisAccount.AmatureRank = 0;
    _thisAccount.AmatureAverage = 0;
    _thisAccount.AmatureScoreOne = 0;
    _thisAccount.AmatureScoreTwo = 0;
    _thisAccount.AmatureScoreThree = 0;
    //Semi
    _thisAccount.SemiProRank = 0;
    _thisAccount.SemiAverage = 0;
    _thisAccount.SemiProScoreOne = 0;
    _thisAccount.SemiProScoreTwo = 0;
    _thisAccount.SemiProScoreThree = 0;
    //Pro
    _thisAccount.ProRank = 0;
    _thisAccount.ProAverage = 0;
    _thisAccount.ProScoreOne = 0;
    _thisAccount.ProScoreTwo = 0;
    _thisAccount.ProScoreThree = 0;

    _thisAccount.accTricks = Account.instance.ReturnTricks();

    string tName = _thisAccount.getAccName();

    Debug.Log("Name: " + tName + " account " + _thisAccount.accTricks.Length);
    Debug.Log("Email: " + _thisAccount.accEmail);
    Debug.Log("Cash: " + _thisAccount.accCash);


    Debug.Log("Attempt to fill Database info");
    ConstuctDatabase(usersdb, _thisAccount);

}


private void ConstuctDatabase(DatabaseReference AccountRef, AccountData _thisAccount)
{
    int num = 0;
    AccountRef.RunTransaction(MutableData =>
    {
        num++;
        List<object> account = MutableData.Value as List<object>;

        if (account == null)
        {
            account = new List<object>();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("continue");
        }



        Dictionary<string, object> newAccount =
            new Dictionary<string, object>();

        newAccount["AccountName"] = _thisAccount.accName;
        newAccount["AccountEmail"] = _thisAccount.accEmail;
        newAccount["Cash"] = _thisAccount.accCash;
        newAccount["Gem"] = _thisAccount.accGem;

        //Ranking Values
        newAccount["Rank"] = _thisAccount.Rank;
        //rookie
        newAccount["RookieRank"] = _thisAccount.RookieRank;
        newAccount["RookieAverage"] = _thisAccount.RookieAverage;
        newAccount["RookieScoreOne"] = _thisAccount.RookieScoreOne;
        newAccount["RookieScoreTwo"] = _thisAccount.RookieScoreTwo;
        newAccount["RookieScoreThree"] = _thisAccount.RookieScoreThree;
        //Amature
        newAccount["AmateurRank"] = _thisAccount.AmatureRank;
        newAccount["AmateurAverage"] = _thisAccount.AmatureAverage;
        newAccount["AmateurScoreOne"] = _thisAccount.AmatureScoreOne;
        newAccount["AmateurScoreTwo"] = _thisAccount.AmatureScoreTwo;
        newAccount["AmateurScoreThree"] = _thisAccount.AmatureScoreThree;
        //Semi
        newAccount["SemiProRank"] = _thisAccount.SemiProRank;
        newAccount["SemiProAverage"] = _thisAccount.SemiAverage;
        newAccount["SemiProScoreOne"] = _thisAccount.SemiProScoreOne;
        newAccount["SemiProScoreTwo"] = _thisAccount.SemiProScoreTwo;
        newAccount["SemiProScoreThree"] = _thisAccount.SemiProScoreThree;
        //Pro
        newAccount["ProRank"] = _thisAccount.ProRank;
        newAccount["ProAverage"] = _thisAccount.ProAverage;
        newAccount["ProScoreOne"] = _thisAccount.ProScoreOne;
        newAccount["ProScoreTwo"] = _thisAccount.ProScoreTwo;
        newAccount["ProScoreThree"] = _thisAccount.ProScoreThree;

        //Trick Logic]
        Dictionary<string, bool> newTricks =
            new Dictionary<string, bool>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < _thisAccount.accTricks.Length)
        {
            newTricks["Trick" + i] = _thisAccount.accTricks[i]._owned;
            i++;
        }

        newAccount["TrickList"] = newTricks;

        Debug.Log("ConstructDB1");
        account.Add(newAccount);
        MutableData.Value = account;
        Debug.Log("ConstructDB2");

        return TransactionResult.Success(MutableData);
    });
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue in 6.6.0. If you pay attention to the [release page](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity), I'd recommend upgrading as soon as possible.

Now an explanation of what's going on with a small workaround: an array is being serialized as effectively a dictionary with a numeric key. It's parsing numbers lexicographically (ex: it's doing some thing like 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...) and it breaks at 11. To work around this, rather than adding a list as you currently are, try serializing a dictionary with lexicographically ordered keys (ex: M001, M002, M003, &c). I know this isn't ideal, but it should unblock you for the time being!